# Integration of the question manually

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[Click here for the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yxQc.png)

Can someone please tell me how to definite integrate this (from zero to infinity) manually?

I know the answer is equal to: 238.023734485098

But i have been unsuccessful

Thank You Very Much

Comment: May be, you could at least tell what are the bounds (even if we can guess them).

Comment: from zero to infinity

Comment: Run the calcs and you'll obtain something like $$\int_0^\infty k_1e^{-\alpha_1 x}+k_2e^{-\alpha_2 x}+\cdots +k_re^{-\alpha_rx}\,dx$$ for positive $\alpha_j$. After doing this, the primitive is easily calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the integrand $$f=1-\left(1-e^{-x/12}\right)^{11} \left(1-e^{-x/24}\right) \left(1-e^{-x/72}\right)^2
   \left(1-e^{-x/144}\right)^2$$ I should start simplifying the problem letting $$e^{-x/144}=y$$ So, the integrand becomes (after a few simplifications) $$f=1-(y-1)^{16} (y+1)^{14} \left(y^4+y^2+1\right)^{12} \left(y^6+1\right)^{11}$$ and you need to find the coefficient of $y^n$; let us call it $c_n$. So, we have $$f=\sum_{n=1}^{144}c_ny^n$$ (notice that the $1$ must disppear by expansion).

Back to $x$, you then need to compute $$\int_0^\infty f\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^{144}\int_0^\infty c_n e^{-nx/144}\,dx=144\sum_{n=1}^{144}\frac{c_n}n$$

If no mistake, you should end with $$\int_0^\infty f\,dx=\frac{19179385249735728551550367428216940591727383888374120235641}{8057761672895
   9000543177737840861586668464761577474749000}$$